# Interior product in an exterior algebra

Tags: differential-geometry

The interior product in the exterior algebra, for a covector $e$ and a k-form $w$, is defined by:

\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
e\lrcorner \omega=(-1)^{n k+n+1} *(e \wedge * \omega)
\end{equation}

Where $*$ is the Hodge star, defined by $\alpha \wedge * \beta=\langle\alpha, \beta\rangle$.

I don't know where $(1)$ comes from. Until now, I knew that the interior product is defined as a contration:

$$
i_{\mathrm{v}} \beta^{p}\left(\mathbf{A}_{2}, \ldots, \mathbf{A}_{p}\right):=\beta^{p}\left(\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{A}_{2}, \ldots, \mathbf{A}_{p}\right)
$$

Where $\mathrm{v}$ is a vector, $\beta^{p}$ a p-form and $\mathbf{A}_{2}, \ldots, \mathbf{A}_{p}$ a vector field.

**Question**: where does $(1)$ come from?

Comment: This should come from the contraction of $\omega$ with the unique vector $v$ dual (using the metric) to the covector $e$. For example, in $\Bbb R^3$ take $\omega = dx\wedge dz$ and $e=dx$; then $\star(dx\wedge\star\omega) = -dy$, which is the negative of the contraction of $dx\wedge dy$ with $\partial/\partial x$.